# Разница во времени на 12 секунд из timestamp

Tags: javascript, symfony, timestamp

Пытаюсь сделать таймер и отобразить оставшееся время на странице.

Время когда таймер стартанул:

```php
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Riga');
$now = new DateTimeImmutable('now', $timeZone);
```

И сохраняю в базу:

```php
$entity->setTimer($now);

$this->em->persist($entity);
$this->em->flush();
```

Беру timestamp:

```php
$dateTime = $entity->getTimer();
$dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Дальше на FE:

```js
const currentD = new Date();
const startD = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
const timer = 5; // Таймер в минутах
let endD = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

endD.setMinutes(startD.getMinutes() + timer);

const remainingTimeMinutes = Math.floor((endD - currentD) / 60000);
const remainingTimeSeconds = (((endD - currentD) % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
```

И почему то **startD** на ~12 секунд больше чем **currentD**. Из-за чего так происходит?

Fri May 20 2022 10:05:04 GMT+0300 // currentD

Fri May 20 2022 10:05:13 GMT+0300 // startD

Comment: А откуда берётся `timestamp` вы не показали

Comment: Потому что часы на сервере или клиенте врут

Comment: Или запрос шёл 12 секунд (но это вряд ли)

Comment: Запрос идет 250 мс. Timestamp приходит аяксом.

Comment: Ну вот значит `timestamp` какой-то левый, надо проверять везде время и как `timestamp` формируется там, откуда он приходит, тоже проверять.